# How to pass a value from AngularJS to Spring REST controller

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am new to AngularJS and Spring MVC. I am trying to call a REST service from AngularJS and validate the login credentials.

I am not sure if I am trying to pass the param in the right way to pass it to the Controller. Please can someone guide me if I am missing any

Controller.js

```
var SupportSystems = angular.module('SupportSystems', [ 'ngResource' ]);
SupportSystems
        .controller(
                'LoginController',
                function($scope, $resource) {
                    $scope.authenticate = function() {
                        var authenticateUser = $resource('http://localhost:8080/SupportSystems/SSystems/authenticateUser/:userName', {userName: '@userName'});
                        authenticateUser.save(function(data) {
                            alert("user->" + $scope.userName);
                            alert("pass->" + $scope.password);
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping("/SSystems")
public class SupportSystemsController { `

    @RequestMapping(value="/authenticateUser/{userName}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> authenticateUser(@RequestParam("userName") String userName) {
        System.out.println("username -->" + userName);
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Error : Required String parameter 'userName' is not present.

I need to pass the value of username and password to Spring controller. I am trying to use @RequestParam

```
<body ng-controller="LoginController">

<form class="login-form" name="loginForm" ng-submit="authenticate()">       
    <h2> Login</h2>
    <input type="text" id="userName" class="form-control" name="userName" required autofocus="autofocus" 
    ng-model="userName" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your original question**: 
You need to use `@PathVariable` instread of `@RequestParam`

**Suggestion**: I suggest you to submit the `username` and `password` data as a body of the `POST` request.

How to send `POST` request with `$http`:

```
$scope.authenticate = function() {
    var data = {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
    };

    var successCallBack = function(response){
        // success response found from server
    };

    var errorCallBack = function(response){
        // error response found from server
    };

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/SupportSystems/SSystems/authenticateUser', data).then(successCallBack, errorCallBack);
}
```

How to process it in Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticateUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody AuthenticateUserRequest request) {

    // check the submitted username and password
    if(request.getUserName().equals("nayan") && request.getPassword().equals("pass")){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Your `AuthenticateUserRequest` class may look like this:

```
public class AuthenticateUserRequest {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public String getUsername(){return this.username;}
    public void setUsername(String username){this.username = username;}
    public String getPassword(){return this.password;}
    public void setPassword(String password){this.password = password;}

}
```

**Notes**:

1. `@Valid` annotation is optional. If present, it'll ensure that `username` and `password` must be submitted to the controller. `@NotNull` annotation checks this validation.
2. In most cases you'll match submitted `username` and `password` values with values from your database. I've skipped that in order to keep it simple.

Comment: I used $http below and was able to fetch the values. Can you explain more about payload        var data = 'userName=' + $scope.userName + '&amp;password=' + $scope.password;
     $http.post('http://localhost:8080/SupportSystems/SSystems/authenticateUser', data)

Comment: I've updated the answer with some sample code. Hope it'll help you.